# NoSuchMethodError: LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss, nosuchmethod

I am using Spring 3.2 and Hibernate4. I included all Jars required. Using JBoss AS. Deploying from Eclipse. But I am getting this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private 
com.springmvcsample.service.PersonService 
com.springmvcsample.controller.PersonController.personService; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private 
com.springmvcsample.dao.PersonDAO com.springmvcsample.service.PersonServiceImpl.personDao; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
name 'personDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is    
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
 org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.springmvcsample.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested 
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
 name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate_config.xml]: 
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass
 (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

Web.xml

```
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name> SpringMVC_Hibernate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
              org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

   <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringMVC_Hibernate-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>SpringMVC_Hibernate</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

SpringMVC_Hibernate-servlet.xml

```
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcsample.controller"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcsample.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcsample.service"/>
    <import resource="hibernate_config.xml"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- Turn off working out content type based on URL file extension, should fall back to looking at the Accept headers -->
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="sender" class="com.springmvcsample.utility.MessageSender"/>
```

hibernate_config.xml

```
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/resources/db.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springmvcsample.controller" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

[image: my lib flder]

Additional jars include:

```
  spring-jms-3.2x.jar 
  spring-orm-*.jar
  spring-tx-*.jar
  spring-web-*.jar
  spring-webmvc-*.jar
```

Comment: all spring jars are from 3.2.0 right

Comment: Thats Right. All are of same version 3.2.0

Comment: Are the libraries actually included in the war file?

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have an older version lying about somewhere.  When I usually see this error, its because I either have conflicting versions of JARs (Version x.x.x is required, but I have x.y.z), or I have two copies lying around, one older and incorrect and one newer and correct, and the older one is getting loaded first.  Also, are you using Maven or some other tool to manage your dependencies, or are you doing this by hand?

Comment: I am doing this by hand. I downloaded all latest versions available. Spring 3.2.0 and Hibernate4.0. Is there a way to check version dependencies among the libraries? All are Jars. Its a Eclipse deploy to JBoss AS. So its a war deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Using Maven makes life easier in such cases.

Opening the pom.xml in IDE like Eclipse / STS will give you a better picture like following:-

[image]