# JBoss error while running Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss

I am working on a Spring MVC app. Running app on Jboss shows following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

But I have all jars in WEB-INF/lib directory. I have included following jars:

```
antlr-3.1.1.jar
antlr-runtime-3.1.jar
aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
dom4j.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.16.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.16.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-4.2.16.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
json-simple-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
logback-classic-1.1.2.jar
logback-core-1.1.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-build-src-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Following is my dispatcher servlet code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"> 

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.scm" />
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/MySqlDS" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.scm"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
```

Can anybody please suggest some solution?

Comment: Do you have pom.xml and persistence context configuration?

Comment: I see the error log info very similar to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966699/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-while-init-sessionfactory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892797/nosuchmethoderror-localsessionfactorybuilder-addannotatedclassljava-lang-class See if this helps.